# Scheduled refresh not working in Power BI

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I just started receiving an error in my scheduled refreshes (and if I select the Refresh Now option) with Power BI Service a few days ago... I don't believe any of my actions changed, but all data sources live on MS Teams (SharePoint).

There's a screenshot below of what I'm receiving. It's also worth noting that while the gateway says it has errors, it also A) says that it's not needed (under Gateway Connection) and B) when I select the option to go fix it, I fix it, test the connection, and it says all good.

After reading elsewhere, I've also installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 and my Power BI Pro diagnostics are below.

Thoughts??

> Last refresh failed: Thu Apr 25 2019 12:47:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
>
> There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.Hide detailsMessage:Excel Workbook: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine 2010 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider may be required to read this type of file. To download the client software, visit the following site: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=285987. Table: Demand.Cluster URI:WABI-US-NORTH-CENTRAL-redirect.analysis.windows.netActivity ID:45fae6fe-f640-4a48-a080-32ef9eda4e63Request ID:f032bb4a-5fbd-b2da-55f6-a59bbcda531dTime:2019-04-25 16:47:48Z "

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your source is Excel files in SharePoint Online, then you shouldn't use a Gateway.  Start your queries from **Get Data / SharePoint folder** and then you will just need to enter credentials for the Dataset after the first time you publish it to the web service.